# Customizing positions of icon and title in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-xml

I have a Navigation drawer with various fragments. Now i need the titles to be displayed right below the icons, also i need to increase the size of the icons. Please, suggest a method so that i can set the layout of Navigation Drawer as the below image:

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Add the text view under the icon and go to the XML file of the icon and make changes in size as per your requirements...

Comment: @niyapanchal i don't have any textview created  in navigation drawer xml file.